# How can I read one tables partial data from hbase with pyspark and shc(spark hbase connector) instead of whole dataset?

Tags: python, pyspark, hbase

I am using pyspark to access hbase's table with shc. The table has a large number of records, but my spark cluster is only three servers and had bad performance. I think it is unreasonable to read the whole data from that hbase table and then deal it with spark's filter, so how could I read partial data from hbase with pyspark and shc?
for example, I want filter rowkey with start value end end value or filter column

there is a basic write and read methods for you, thanks

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('localhost').appName('test_1').getOrCreate()

def test_shc():
    catalog = ''.join("""{
      "table":{"namespace":"test", "name":"test_shc"},
      "rowkey":"key",
      "columns":{
      "col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
      "col1":{"cf":"result", "col":"class", "type":"string"}
      }
      }""".split())

    data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'
    df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('a', '1.0'), ('b', '2.0')]).toDF(schema=['col0', 'col1'])
    df.show()
    df.write.options(catalog=catalog, newTable="5").format(data_source_format).save()
    df_read = spark.read.options(catalog=catalog).format(data_source_format).load()
    df_read.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`spark.read.options(catalog=catalog).format(data_source_format).load().limit(n)`

while loading the data. `limit(n)` will limit the amount of records that will be read.

Comment: Thanks, but how to realize the function to fetch a range of rowkey's data ?  if the  rowkey like '20190804xxxxx', and I want to get the data in a given time frame such as (20190705, 20190803]

Answer (score 0):

Since then, you have probably found the answer... However, the way you can avoid loading the whole file, but only the lines you want is exactly what you said, in other words applying the filter based on the rowkey after loading.
In this way **SHC will not load the whole table**, since the filters will be pushed down on HBase and only the data in the filter will return to Spark, as you can see here: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/issues/108, where

```
def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
  sqlContext 
  .read
  .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .load()
 }
```

Please note that filtering on a non-rowkey column results in a full scan of the table. In this case querying is not very efficient and one suggested way is to push computing to the HBase layer using the SingleColumnValueFilter to filter as much as possible before transferring data to Spark.

For more details: https://www.ifi.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:fbf88795-65a3-4bc1-9a8a-60548d7f2f91/SHC%20Distributed%20Query%20Processing.pdf